# Brushing/linking in vega (not vega-lite)

Tags: vega

I'm trying to brush/link two plots in vega, more specifically a node-link diagram and a couple of scatterplots. Based on how dragging works with signals in the node-link diagram I did get quite far, but not far enough...

For the sake of simplicity, I'll provide a little test code here using just two scatterplots:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "padding": 0,
  "autosize": "none",
  "width": 800,
  "height": 400,

  "signals": [
    { "description": "Any datapoint is activated",
      "name": "datapoint_is_activated", "value": false,
      "on": [
        {
          "events": "symbol:mouseover",
          "update": "true"
        },
        {
          "events": "symbol:mouseout",
          "update": "false"
        }
      ]
    },
    { "description": "Active datapoint",
      "name": "activated_datapoint", "value": null,
      "on": [
        {
          "events": "symbol:mouseover",
          "update": "item()"
        },
        {
          "events": "symbol:mouseout",
          "update": "null"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],

  "data": [
    {
      "name": "table",
      "values": [
        {"name": "point A", "a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3},
        {"name": "point B", "a": 4, "b": 5, "c": 6},
        {"name": "point C", "a": 9, "b": 8, "c": 7}
      ]
    }
  ],

  "scales": [
    { "name": "xscale",
      "type": "linear",
      "domain": [0,10],
      "range": [0,200]
    },
    { "name": "yscale",
      "type": "linear",
      "domain": [0,10],
      "range": [0,200]
    }
  ],

  "layout": {"padding": 20},

  "marks": [
    { "name": "plot1",
      "type": "group",
      "axes": [
        {"orient": "bottom", "scale": "xscale"},
        {"orient": "right", "scale": "yscale"}
      ],
      "marks": [
        {
          "type": "symbol",

          "from": {"data": "table"},

          "encode": {
            "enter": {
              "x": {"field": "a", "scale": "xscale"},
              "y": {"field": "b", "scale": "yscale"},
              "tooltip": {"field": "name"}
            },
            "update": {
              "size": {"value": 100},
              "fill": {"value": "grey"}
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    { "name": "plot2",
      "type": "group",
      "axes": [
        {"orient": "bottom", "scale": "xscale"},
        {"orient": "right", "scale": "yscale"}
      ],
      "marks": [
        {
          "type": "symbol",

          "from": {"data": "table"},

          "on": [
            {
              "trigger": "datapoint_is_activated",
              "modify": "activated_datapoint",
              "values": "{fill: \"red\"}"
            },
            {
              "trigger": "!datapoint_is_activated",
              "modify": "activated_datapoint",
              "values": "{fill: \"grey\"}"
            }
          ],

          "encode": {
            "enter": {
              "x": {"field": "a", "scale": "xscale"},
              "y": {"field": "c", "scale": "yscale"},
              "size": {"value": 100},
              "tooltip": {"field": "name"}
            },
            "update": {
              "fill": {"value": "grey"}
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The resulting image looks like this:
[image: Two linked plots]

The idea is that hovering over a datapoint in the *left* plot will highlight the corresponding datapoint in the *right* plot. I know this is straightforward in vega-lite, but that does not (yet) support node-link diagrams. Hence: vega.

My approach in the code is to:

- create a signal in the outer scope that tracks (a) if there is a point activated, and (b) which point this is
- in plot 2 to have a trigger that takes the activated datapoint and changes its colour to 'red'.

I have an inkling feeling that it has to do with my definition of the `modify` and `values` part, but I can't figure it out.

Any help very much appreciated!

Thank you,
jan.

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of trial and error, I did find a way to do this. Instead of using a `trigger` (which I believe would be the canonical way of doing this), I merely use a `test` in the `fill` section: `datapoint_is_activated && datum === activated_datapoint.datum`. See code and image below.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "padding": 0,
  "autosize": "none",
  "width": 800,
  "height": 400,

  "signals": [
    { "description": "Any datapoint is activated",
      "name": "datapoint_is_activated", "value": false,
      "on": [
        {
          "events": "symbol:mouseover",
          "update": "true"
        },
        {
          "events": "symbol:mouseout",
          "update": "false"
        }
      ]
    },
    { "description": "Active datapoint",
      "name": "activated_datapoint", "value": null,
      "on": [
        {
          "events": "symbol:mouseover",
          "update": "item()"
        },
        {
          "events": "symbol:mouseout",
          "update": "null"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],

  "data": [
    {
      "name": "table",
      "values": [
        {"name": "point A", "a": 2, "b": 2, "c": 4},
        {"name": "point B", "a": 4, "b": 5, "c": 6},
        {"name": "point C", "a": 5, "b": 3, "c": 5}
      ]
    }
  ],

  "scales": [
    { "name": "xscale",
      "type": "linear",
      "domain": [0,10],
      "range": [0,200]
    },
    { "name": "yscale",
      "type": "linear",
      "domain": [0,10],
      "range": [0,200]
    }
  ],

  "layout": {"padding": 20},

  "marks": [
    { "name": "plot1",
      "type": "group",
      "axes": [
        {"orient": "bottom", "scale": "xscale"},
        {"orient": "right", "scale": "yscale"}
      ],
      "marks": [
        {
          "type": "symbol",

          "from": {"data": "table"},

          "encode": {
            "enter": {
              "x": {"field": "a", "scale": "xscale"},
              "y": {"field": "b", "scale": "yscale"},
              "tooltip": {"field": "name"},
              "size": {"value": 200}
            },
              "update": {
              "fill": [
                {"test": "datapoint_is_activated && datum === activated_datapoint.datum",
                "value": "red"},
                {"value": "lightgrey"}
              ]

            }
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    { "name": "plot2",
      "type": "group",
      "axes": [
        {"orient": "bottom", "scale": "xscale"},
        {"orient": "right", "scale": "yscale"}
      ],
      "marks": [
        {
          "type": "symbol",

          "from": {"data": "table"},

          "encode": {
            "enter": {
              "x": {"field": "a", "scale": "xscale"},
              "y": {"field": "c", "scale": "yscale"},
              "size": {"value": 200},
              "tooltip": {"field": "name"}
            },
            "update": {
              "fill": [
                {"test": "datapoint_is_activated && datum === activated_datapoint.datum",
                "value": "red"},
                {"value": "lightgrey"}
              ]

            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

[image: brushing linking]

Comment: I spent longer than I'd like to admit trying to do something similar. After looking through the docs and other examples it was your answer that finally helped. hanky ouT (its an anagram because SE)